# Sublime Text 3 and Javascript Completions package not working

Tags: sublimetext3

I am using ST3 on Windows and have installed the package from the website -- https://packagecontrol.io/packages/JavaScript%20Completions

But I am unable to get the pop-ups to work as expected like the example on the packagecontrol.io website.

Are there some settings or anything that can or need to be turned on to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the entire README on the page you linked? Do you have Node.js installed and properly configured in the plugin?

Comment: Fortunately yes I did read the README which is on that page. Nodejs was installed as well. I ended up figuring it out. and needed to turn on a couple auto completions and restart ST3. All is well.

Comment: Glad to hear it. You'd be surprised at the number of people that ask questions here that are clearly answered in the respective READMEs...

Answer (score 1):

After turning on a few other autocompletions and saving the preferences, I restarted Sublime Text 3 and the menu started showing up.